# Why is breeze.js not mapping properties as dependent observables?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, hottowel

John Papa's [single page app jumpstart tutorial](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=single-page-apps-jumpstart&highlight=) adds a property called "isPartial" to its entities to determine if the entire entity has been loaded into the cache by breeze.  When I ran this using the tutorial with Breeze.WebApi version 1.1.3, everything ran fine.  However, I am now running the tutorial with the HotTowel Visual Studio template for VS 2013 (version 1.1) and I see a problem with saving entities where breeze (version 1.4.1) gets a "Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function" on breeze.debug.js line 15124.

The line in question is trying to access the "isPartial" property on the entity:

```
    proto.getProperty = function(propertyName) {
        return this[propertyName]();
    };
```

The difference between the earlier version and now is that when the "isPartial" property is attached in the constructor, like this:

```
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
        'Session', function () { this.isPartial = false; }, sessionInitializer);
```

... the property is a "ko.dependentObservable".  In the newer version, it is a simple property.  My guess is that is what is causing the problem in breeze.  Actually, it seems that when the entity is first loaded, the "isPartial" property is also a dependentObservable (and the save can work without error).  However, sometime after this it becomes a simple property.

Here is a chrome debug shot of the before value that works.
[image]

Here is a chrome debug shot of the after that doesn't work.
[image]

Thanks for any clues!

Comment: Try upgrading breeze.js to version >= 1.4.4. In [the doc](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download#144) it says version 1.4.4 resolves Knockout wrapping bugs

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading breeze.js to version >= 1.4.4.

In **[the doc](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download#144)** it says version 1.4.4 resolves Knockout wrapping bugs:

> Fixed a bug with ES5 props in knockout not always being wrapped properly.

Comment: Good idea!  I updated to 1.4.4 and then to 1.4.13 without any difference.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @MikeWitt It was worth a try! It's hard to get ideas without further information. Do you get this problem when you run the tutorial step by step or did you adapt to your own case?

Comment: On the first pass (that worked), I followed the tutorial step by step.  On this pass, I substituted other ideas (different entities) but the concept was the same.  I may take the first pass that worked and upgrade it's nuget packages to newer versions (although the original is Durandal 1.0 and the new is 2.0 so this will add some effort).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There must be another explanation. You'll see examples like yours in the [DocCode sample, *entityExtensionTests.js*](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode/tests/entityExtensionTests.js). For example:

```
test("add unmapped 'isPartial' property via constructor", 6, function () {
    var store = cloneModuleMetadataStore();

    var Customer = function () {
        // These are simple 'field' properties.
        // Breeze converts them to the right kind of properties  
        // for the prevailing modelLibrary adapter
        // such as KO observable properties.
        this.CustomerID = testFns.newGuidComb();
        this.isPartial = true;
    };

    store.registerEntityTypeCtor('Customer', Customer);

    var em = newEm(store);
    var cust = em.createEntity('Customer'); 

    assertExpectedCustomerCtorProperties(cust);
});

function assertExpectedCustomerCtorProperties(cust) {
    var custType = cust.entityType;
    ok(custType,"'cust' is now an entity");

    // Breeze converted both into KO observables
    ok(typeof cust.CustomerID === 'function',
        "'CustomerID' should be a KO observable");

    ok(typeof cust.isPartial === 'function',
        "'isPartial' should be a KO observable");

    if (!custType) {return;} // no remaining tests would pass

    var propInfo = custType.getProperty('CustomerID');
    ok(propInfo && !propInfo.isUnmapped && propInfo.isPartOfKey,
        "'CustomerID' should be detected as a mapped property");

    propInfo = custType.getProperty('isPartial');
    ok(propInfo && propInfo.isUnmapped,
        "'isPartial' should be an unmapped property");

    var unmapped = custType.unmappedProperties;
    ok(unmapped.length === 1,
        "'isPartial' should be the lone unmapped property");

}
```

Your 2nd screen shot is clearly for a different entity than the first so it does not persuade me that the problem lies with breeze.

I strongly recommend the documentation on extending entities, particularly for its explanation of the differences between properties in a custom constructor and an initializer.

IMO, for your purpose, you want the `isPartial` property in your constructor